# Rewrite dynamic query string on two difrend pages with same string value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wampserver

Hello my problem is rewriting URL of two different pages that have same query value.
Example: `/players.php?name=Messi` and `/clubs.php?name=Barcelona`

My `.htaccess` is :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+club\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-Football-Wallpapers? [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)-Football-Wallpapers/?$ /club.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+player\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-Football-Wallpapers? [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-Football-Wallpapers/?$ /player.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]<br>
```

If i use only one of the rules everything is ok for **club.php?name=barcelona** page, but when i use both of them and i try to open **player.php?name=messi** i get redirect to **club.php**. 
Is it possible to mistake in flag i use?

Comment: Use 2 different pretty URL schemes. For example `%1-Football-Clubs` and `%1-Football-Players`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one same rule for 2 different pages. The rewrite engine does not make any difference, it takes the first one (here club.php)

A simple example is to add something in player rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-Football-Wallpapers-Player/?$ /player.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now you have an internal redirect from `Football-Wallpapers` to `club.php` and `Football-Wallpapers-Player` to `player.php`